# Upgrading Vite version is messing with styling

Tags: css, vue.js, vite, rollup

I am working on an old project that contains a substantial amount of outdated CSS and code written in jQuery, vanilla JavaScript, and more.
We are in the process of migrating to Vue (v2) along with Vuetify and Vite.
Currently, we have a mix of CSS styles, Vuetify, and Bootstrap, and these styles are interfering with and disrupting our build process. To address this issue, we have consolidated all the generated CSS, including 'chunk-vendors.css,' into a single stylesheet with a wrapper class. This separation ensures that the Vuetify code exclusively modifies the Vue/Vuetify code.

However, after updating to Vite v4.4.5, it appears that there is an issue where Vite automatically injects the vendor styles into the DOM. Is there any way to prevent Rollup/Vite from automatically injecting these styles into the DOM? I have a multi-page application (MPA) where I manually import all the necessary stylesheets into the specific files where they are needed.

Upon inspecting the stylesheet, it seems that the 'plugin-vue2_normalizer' is responsible for inserting it into the DOM.

Here is my 'vite.config':

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { VuetifyResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/wwwroot/dist/',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.mjs',
      '.js',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.jsx',
      '.json',
      '.vue',
      '.scss'
    ],
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '~': fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules', import.meta.url)),
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    minify: true,
    // We can't minify css because Visual Studio won't be able to import the chunk-vendors minified css file
    cssMinify: false,
    sourcemap: false,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    outDir: 'wwwroot/dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: { ... },
      output: {
        dir: 'wwwroot/dist',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        assetFileNames: 'css/[name].css',
        chunkFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
          return chunkInfo.name === 'chunk-vendors' ? 'js/chunk-vendors.js' : 'js/chunk.[name]-[hash].js';
        },
        manualChunks: (id) => {
          if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
            return 'chunk-vendors';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Components({
      resolvers: [
        VuetifyResolver()
      ],
      dts: 'src/declaration-files/components.d.ts'
    })
  ]
});
```

- I have tried to change the Vite config's manualChunks, and ignoring the normalizer chunk. But it doesn't seem to work.
- In the release notes it mentions that they've changed the build to inject stylesheets, but I can't find a solution to revert it.